# Cant get info which button was clicked

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms

I have 2 buttons in my form and I need to get info about which button was clicked.

I found fix, but it doesnt work for me.

HTML/PHP:

```
                <form class=\"akcje_konkretne\" method=\"post\">
                        <input type=\"hidden\" class=\"id_user\" value=\"$stat[id]\">
                        <input type=\"hidden\" class=\"id_movie\" value=\"$podobny_film[id]\">
                    <button type=\"submit\" name=\"obejrzany\" value=\"obejrzany\" class=\"btn read-more post--btn\">obejrzany</button>
                    <button type=\"submit\" name=\"usun\" value=\"usun\" class=\"btn read-more post--btn usun\">usuń</button>
                    </form>
```

jQuery:

```
                  $('form.akcje_konkretne').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var $form = $(this);
        var id_movie = $form.find('.id_movie').val();
        var id_user = $form.find('.id_user').val();
        var btn = $(e.target).text();

        alert('you have clicked '+ btn);


      });
```

Now with `e.target` I get alerts with 2 button values: **you have clicked obejrzany usun**

Comment: `e` is the event representing the click, and should have a `.target` attribute, which is the element which was clicked.

Comment: @MarcB where I should put that target attribute? Dont know how to do that, never had that problem.

Comment: `e.target` will be the dom node the click occured on. e.g. `e.target.name` will be `obejrzany` or whatever.

Comment: @MarcB still dont know how to do it. I just don't know how to use that knowledge in my script.. :(

Comment: I have no idea either. You said "need to get info about which button was clicked", and `e.target` **IS** the button which was clicked. How you use that information is up to you.

Comment: @MarcB Yep but e.target gives me 2 alerts. My code: `var btn = $(e.target).text();
   
   alert('you have clicked '+ btn);` I get 2 alerts from that: **you have clicked: obejrzany usun**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the event target to get the button's info -

```
$('button').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(e.target.value);
    var currentUser = $(this).closest('form').find('.id_user').val();
    var currentMovie = $(this).closest('form').find('.id_movie').val();
    console.log(currentUser);
    console.log(currentMovie);
});
```

EDIT: Updated [example](http://jsfiddle.net/gpcx5dcn/1/)

Comment: How I can make that work with my code? I mean, Im not starting with  `$('button').click(function(e) {` but `$('form.akcje_konkretne').submit(function(e) {`?

Comment: You need a .each() in there since there's more than one button.

Comment: You don't need the submit function here as you can send the form data where it needs to go based on the button clicked in the form.

Comment: No need for an `each()` @Jackhardcastle. Look at the example.

Comment: Oh okay yeah, find() would suffice too.

Comment: What would you use `find()` for @Jackhardcastle?

Comment: input[type=submit]:focus

would get the button that is being clicked upon the form submission.

Comment: Yes @Jackhardcastle, that will get you the button object details. `e.target` is much quicker and cleaner, allowing you to address the object far more easily.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Yep but e.target gives me 2 alerts. My code: `var btn = $(e.target).text(); alert('you have clicked '+ btn);` I get 2 alerts from that: you have clicked: obejrzany usun

Comment: Did you look at the example @MichałLipa?

Comment: @JayBlanchard Yes, I saw the example but dont know how to use this example. I mean that I need to get all data to values to send that futher. How for example can I make variable from `console.log(e.target.value);`?

Comment: Use `var buttonName = e.target.value;` Other than that my updated example shows how to get the values. You can pass them along with AJAX.

Answer (score -1):

```
$('button').each(function() {
    $(this).click(function() {
        console.log($(this));
    );
});
```

Will give you some information about each button clicked.